# How to add profile shortcode to WordPress sidebar (i.e., in widget)

Tags: wordpress, profile

I can add a newsletter signup Profile shortcode to a page or post in Wordpress, but I'd like to have it show up on the sidebar.  I put the shortcode into a text widget (the code is for our MailMunch signup is in a text widget) but the Civi shortcode doesn't work there.

See http://sandbox.bio4climate.org/

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Adam

P.S. - This is a test site (but the payment processor is live!).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just adding the HTML form snippet to the text widget? It's not as neat as adding a shortcode, but it should work okay.

Go to Administer CiviCRM > Profiles, then HTML Form Snippet under 'more' for your chosen snippet. Copy all the code there and paste it into your text widget.

Comment: Thanks liblogger - it works!  Needs a bit of adjustment to fit in the narrow column, but this newbie is on his way.  Regards to all!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like a custom plugin / extension job.

Be advised of the following:
1. Some versions of WordPress & CiviCRM only support one hook implementation across all plugins. I recommend building it in a civi extension to circumvent this.
2. Unless you are yourself a software developer, if you do need a custom plugin, I suspect you'd best recruit a freelancer. I'll happily bid, otherwise there's the excellent CiviCRM partnership organisations.